# Remove 'Reply-To' Field when Writing an email in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

In Thunderbird 5.0, I hit `Write:` to compose a new email message.  One of the fields is `Reply-To:`, which comes up with the email address I set it to in the options.

While I appreciate the flexibility of being able to choose different reply-tos, for what I'm using it for I'll never need to change it.

Is there a way of keeping this field from even coming up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the Account or Identity has the Reply-To field filled in, clear this field in either Account Settings or Manage Identities.  This will stop the field from being filled when you compose a message.  Thunderbird will still append the From email address as the Reply-To address.

Answer (score 0):

It is a field that is needed by the protocol of mail servers. It goes out whether you fill it in or not. If you leave it blank in the options and also in the draft, the address will be automatically filled with the default, which is your main address. But the address that an email will be sent to if someone clicks their "Reply" button is that address.

It is not a field that is visible to recipients.

Comment: I know what the Reply-To field is and made sure to set it correctly in the settings.  I just want it to not appear when I'm writing a message, like most other email clients.  Question clarified.